# Light traveling in glass transmitted through an air gap

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, geometric-optics

Consider a plane wave traveling in glass incident on a small air-gap. The situation is illustrated below (reflected fields omitted) for arbitrary materials.

[image]

My professor derived the expression for the transmitted light relative to the incident light. In the derivation he used that we can evaluate the expressions for the plane waves at $x=0$ (because we are considering plane waves on flat interfaces he said). However, I do not understand why we can do that when $x$ is clearly not constant unless the incident angle is zero?

Comment: The "x = 0" statement just locates those vectors in your picture. For example, if the professor asks where do vectors E2(s) and E3(s) meet - how would you give the (x,z) position?

Comment: But he evaluates the plane waves in all three media with $x=0$ simultaneously, as if they are all independent of $x$?

Comment: I suspect the formulas are independent of x. Plane waves are of infinite extent, so parts with different x look the same, but they are delayed or advanced in time. Do the professor's formulas use time?

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. No, he evaluates the fields at $t=0$.